# opengl, how to best update headers with visual studio?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm having a bit of an issue updating my GL headers. Basically I want to access the function `glCompressedTexImage2D` but my gl headers are really old and I don't believe that function exists in those headers. So I've tried to update my `gl.h` file but I get loads of errors. I've tried updating my graphics card software among other things. Can anyone be of help?

Answer (score 5):

> I'm having a bit of an issue updating my GL headers.

That's because you're not supposed to do this. In Windows anything beyond OpenGL-1.1 is gathered through the extension mechanism. The easiest way to access this is through [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net). Install this and use `GL/glew.h` instead of the regular `GL/gl.h`. Then after a OpenGL context has been created the first thing to call is `glewInit()`.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Windows is stuck on an old version of OpenGL (1.2?). Try using [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net.nyud.net/basic.html) or [Glee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) to load the needed extension ([GL_ARB_TEXTURE_COMPRESSION](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_compression.txt) in the case of `glCompressedTexImage2D`). These libraries will load the available extensions and let you check in your code if a particular extension is loaded or not.

Example with GLEE:

```
#include <gl/GLee.h>          

if (GLEE_ARB_TEXTURE_COMPRESSION)
{
    glCompressedTexImage2D(...);  
}
else
{
     // the extension is not available, use a different method
}
```

Note that GLEE does not require you to explicitly initialize it (unlike GLEW). I strongly recommend this method over manually loading a function pointer. Not because it's my answer :), but because this will also take care of finding out if the hardware and its driver supports the extension (which could be very messy), and it is platform-independent.

Comment: Note that GLEE is defunct and no longer being updated. It stopped at GL 3.3; there have been 6 versions of OpenGL released since then. So however much you may like the style, you shouldn't use it. There are [a number of alternatives for loading OpenGL functions](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library).

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if the current device supports the function, and then get the address of the function before you can call it:

```
PFNGLCOMPRESSEDTEXIMAGE2DPROC p = NULL;
const char* string = glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);

if (strstr(string, "GL_ARB_texture_compression") != NULL)
   p = (PFNGLCOMPRESSEDTEXIMAGE2DPROC)wglGetProcAddress("glCompressedTexImage2D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the: http://www.opengl.org/registry/
and download newest version of [glext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/glext.h) and [wglext.h](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/wglext.h)

Now you will be able to manually get function pointer to features that you want.
Under Windows there is only OpenGL **1.1**.

For a beginner I suggest using GLEW (GLEE is also great but has not been updated for quite a long time...)